# el operador '==' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo int

Tags: c#

Tengo este mensaje de error al llamar o crear un `enum`, este el enumerador

```
public enum mexTipAutent :int
{
 mvxBD = 2,
 mvxWA = 4,
 mvxAPP = 8,
}
```

y esta es la llamada donde me marca el error

```
if (pnTipAutent == clsBaseDatos.mexTipAutent.mvxBD)
{
}
```

gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `pnTipAutent`?

Comment: concuerdo con @SJuan76  , ¿que tipo de dato es la variable con la que lo comparas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes comparar un `enum` con un `int`, debes comparar su tipo subyacente.

Extraído de la documentación oficial, página de referencia de [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

> El tipo subyacente especifica la cantidad de almacenamiento asignado a cada enumerador. No obstante, **se necesita una conversión explícita** para convertir un tipo enum a un tipo entero

Es decir, debes utilizar:

```
if( pnTipAutent == (int)clsBaseDatos.mexTipAutent.mvxBD )
```

Un saludo